# SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificatechain: PartialChain

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, nuget, nuget-package

Here is info about our technical development environment :

- .NET 6
- C# 10
- Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996
- Visual Studio 2022
- Windows 10 Enterprise

Here is the content of the Dockerfile that is associated with our Visual Studio 2022 solution:

> #See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build
> your images for faster debugging.
>
> #Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement
> may need to be changed.
> #For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat
>
> #Step 1 : Create the base
>
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base WORKDIR /app EXPOSE 443
>
> #Step 2 : Deploy the SDK
>
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
>
> WORKDIR /src
>
> COPY ["nuget.config", "."]
>
> COPY ["src/WebUI.csproj", "src/"]
>
> RUN dotnet dev-certs https --clean
>
> RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
>
> RUN dotnet nuget add source
>
> "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-group/" --name  OurPackageSourceRepo
>
> RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
>
> RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-secret/"  --name OurPackageSourceRepo-Secret
>
> RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
>
> RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-dll/" --name OurPackageSourceRepo-DLL
>
> RUN dotnet restore "src/WebUI.csproj"
>
> COPY . . WORKDIR "/src/src"
>
> RUN dotnet build "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
>
> #Step 3 Publish the app
>
> FROM build AS publish
>
> RUN dotnet publish "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
>
> FROM base AS final WORKDIR /app
>
> COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
>
> ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebUI.dll"]

From Windows powershell, I executed the following:

> docker build .

> CACHED [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app
> 0.0s CACHED [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s CACHED [build  2/15] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s CACHED [build  3/15] COPY [nuget.config, .]                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s CACHED [build  4/15] COPY [src/WebUI.csproj, src/]                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s CACHED [build  5/15] RUN dotnet dev-certs https --clean                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s CACHED [build  6/15] RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s CACHED [build  7/15] RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-group/" --name OurPackageSourceRepo CACHED
>
> [build  8/15] RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
>
> 0.0s CACHED [build  9/15] RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-secret/" --name OurPackageSourceRepo-Secret
>
> CACHED [build 10/15] RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
>
> 0.0s CACHED [build 11/15] RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-dll/" --name OurPackageSourceRepo-DLL
>
> [build 12/15] RUN dotnet restore "src/WebUI.csproj"      Retrying
>
> 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
> 'https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-group/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>
> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>
> The
> remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate
> chain: PartialChain Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
> 'https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-secret/FindPackagesById()?
> id='Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>
> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The
> remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate
> chain: PartialChain Dockerfile:23
>
> 21      RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
>
> 22      RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-dll/" --name OurPackageSourceRepo-DLL
>
> 23   RUN dotnet restore "src/WebUI.csproj"
>
> 24      COPY . . 25      WORKDIR "/src/src"
>
> ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet restore
> "src/WebUI.csproj"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Our firm has their own server for nuget package sources, and within our docker file shown above, we add them like so:

> RUN dotnet nuget add source  "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-group/" --name  OurPackageSourceRepo

> RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-secret/"  --name OurPackageSourceRepo-Secret

> RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://blahBlahUrl/nuget-dll/" --name OurPackageSourceRepo-DLL

However, when we run the following in windows powershell:

> docker build .

We keep receiving the following error:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>
> The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

What steps do I need to take to get rid of the remote certificate error shown above?